# SAS SQL inner join two columns able to match one column

Tags: sql, sas

How can I do something like `select * from T1 inner join T2 on (T1.ID=T2.ID OR T1.ID2=T2.ID)`
When I execute this code, it seems to fall in a infinity loop so I guess I'm wrong.

In other words, how can I match one of two columns from T1 to one column from T2

T1

```
ID ID2
1  10
2  20
```

T2

```
ID  value
1   dummy10
20  dummy20
```

Result

```
ID ID2 value
1  10  dummy10
2  20  dummy20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
select *
from T1, T2
where T1.ID = T2.ID or T1.ID2 = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 select statements with union, like this:

```
select 
    t1.ID, 
    t1.ID2, 
    t2.value
from Table1 as t1
inner join Table2 as t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID

UNION 

select 
    t1.ID, 
    t1.ID2, 
    t2.value
from Table1 as t1
inner join Table2 as t2 on t1.ID2 = t2.ID
/* this will exclude values selected by other statement */
where t1.ID2 not in (select ID2 from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see with the code you provide is that you have not specified from which table you want the common column `ID` to be selected:

```
proc sql;
  select
    t1.*
    ,t2.value
  from t1
  inner join t2
  on t1.id = t2.id or t1.id2 = t2.id;
quit;
```

Otherwise, your code should work. Perhaps the size of the data being joined is the problem?